# how to make a tabpage inaccessible in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, methods, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, tabcontrol

I currently have a tabcontrol with 3 tabpages (lets call them A,B, and C) the thing is I want the user to only be able to click certian tabs (if on tabA only can navigate to tabB, if on tabC only can navigate to tabA...) is there a way to do this? I'm a bit stumped, any help is appreciated thanks!

--C#2.0
--Windows Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook up to the Selecting event on the TabControl and inside the event handler, you could check some class variable specifying which tab(s) are allowed to be clicked. If the one you're selecting doesn't match the variable, you can cancel the event.

Comment: I'm just curious what variable im using to disable the page.. someone below had suggested tabpageA.enabled=true; etc.. but I'm using C#2.0 so .enabled isnt possible. suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion was to keep some class level variable, e.g. A string, so in your Selecting handler, you could say "is the tab being selected equal to the tab name in the variable...no? Then canel event"

Answer (score 1):

In order to control which `TabPages` you can navigate to at a time, you can use the `Enabled` property on the `TabPage`. Set it to false in order to prevent any user from being able to interact with it.

In order to dynamically decide which tabs are enabled based on what tab is open you can use the `Selected` event on the `TabControl` (detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected.aspx). This will fire whenever you change the current tab on the `TabControl`. In here, you can determine what the current `TabPage` is and then use that to enable or disable `TabPages` as appropriate.

Comment: You wouldn't want to handle the Selected event, as that's fired only after a tab is selected. OP wants to prevent selection of tabs, which would have to be done WHILE the tab is being selected, via the Selecting event

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler to the [TabControl.Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting.aspx) event to check whether you want to allow the tabpage selection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
If (SelectedIndex == 1) //tab a
{
    tabC.enabled = false;
    tabB.enabled = true;
}
```